# Firebase Cloud functions timeout

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

The following function works well when tested with shell, and data are created in firestore.
When pushed in prod, it returns `Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`

Any input?

```
exports.synchronizeAzavista = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {

    console.log('New User Created');

    const user = event.data;
    const email = user.email;
    const uid = user.uid;

    return admin.database().ref(`/delegates`)
        .orderByChild(`email`)
        .equalTo(email)
        .once("child_added").then(snap => {
            const fbUserRef = snap.key;

            return admin.firestore().collection(`/users`).doc(`${fbUserRef}`).set({
                email: email,
                uid: uid
            }).then(() => console.log("User Created"));
        });
});
```

**Edit**

I've update my code with the following, but I still getting `Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value` but I can't identify where my function return undefined. Why my `getUser()` function does not return anything?

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.synchronizeAzavista = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {

    console.log('New User Created');//This log

    const user = event.data;
    const email = user.email;
    const uid = user.uid;

    console.log('Const are set');//This log

    getUser(email).then(snap => {

        console.log("User Key is " + snap.key);//No log

        const fbUserRef = snap.key;

        return admin.firestore().collection(`/users`).doc(`${fbUserRef}`).set({
            email: email,
            uid: uid
        });
    }).then(() => console.log("User Data transferred in Firestore"));
});

function getUser(email) {

    console.log("Start GetUser for " + email);//This log 

    const snapKey = admin.database().ref(`/delegates`).orderByChild(`email`).equalTo(email).once("child_added").then(snap => {
        console.log(snap.key);//No Log here
return snap;
    });
    return snapKey;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not returning a promise from your write to Firestore.

```
exports.synchronizeAzavista = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    const user = event.data;
    const email = user.email;
    const uid = user.uid;

    return admin.database().ref(`/delegates`)
        .orderByChild(`email`)
        .equalTo(email)
        .once("child_added").then(snap => {
            const fbUserRef = snap.key;

            return admin.firestore().collection(`/users`).doc(`${fbUserRef}`).set({
                email: email,
                uid: uid
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank, does it means the then() kill the promise of the set()?

Comment: No - the Problem is not the 'then' - you can include a then-part, but you need to return the Promise, so Firebase knows it has to keep your function alive until that promise resolves. - And firebase can then interpret the result of the Promise as success or error (rejected promise)